# Is there exist an open connected domain $U$ on which $f$ is never zero but $|f_{|u}|$ attains its minimum at some points of U

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the following statement is True/false ?

suppose that $f$ is  non constant analytics function defined  over $\mathbb{C}$ then

there  exist an open connected domain  $U$ on which $f$  is never zero but $|f_{|u}|$ attains its  minimum at some points of U

my attempts : i thinks  This statement  is  False take $f(z) = e^z$

Comment: i edits  its ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use Liouville theorem which says That is, every holomorphic/Analytic function f for which there exists a positive number $M$ such that $f(z)$ $\leq$ $M$
for all $z$ in  $\mathbb{C}$ is constant.

Use function $g(z)$ $=$ 1/$f(z)$ since f is never zero it is analytic what can you say if minimum of f exist at open domain U.